# How to turn on bluetooth of mobile by using react-native-ble-plx?

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-plx

My mobile app has functionality to turn on Bluetooth of mobile and show list of Bluetooth devices on the screen. I am using react-native-ble-plx lib for achieving this functionality. I need to turn on BLE of mobile by using react-native-ble-plx lib. Any method is available in that lib for turn on BLE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

react-native-ble-plx does not have this functionality but you can use [react-native-bluetooth-state-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bluetooth-state-manager). It allows you to read the current bluetooth state (enabled/disabled) and open the bluetooth settings page on iOS and android. It is even possible to enable (and disable) bluetooth on android without user interaction but you have to add the `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission to you manifest.

But I would suggest you do not activate Bluetooth without user interaction. Simply check the state and show a message like

> Bluetooth is required to use this app. Please activate it trough your settings

Only allow the usage of the rest of the app after bluetooth got enabled. A user is probably confused if he deactivated bluetooth and it is suddenly activated.

Comment: Thank you @M. Kotzjan for your help.

Comment: If this works for you please accept and upvote the answer so others can find it if they are having the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Is now possible to turn ON Bluetooth using react-native-ble-plx.
Working example with Alert:

```
const subscription = BLTManager.onStateChange((state) => {  // check if device bluetooth is powered on, if not alert to enable it!
        if (state === 'PoweredOff') {
          Alert.alert('"App" would like to use Bluetooth.', 'This app uses Bluetooth to connect to and share information with your .....', [
            {
              text: "Don't allow",
              onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
              style: 'cancel',
            },
            { text: "Turn ON", onPress: () => { BLTManager.enable(); scanDevices() } },
          ]);

          subscription.remove();
        }
      }, true);
```